# Regex pattern for abbreviation and punctuation mark

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I have a paragraph and I want to tokenize it by separating the punctuation from the words, and print the result. There are special cases (abbreviations  such as U.S.A & apostrophe such as Peter's, and decimal numbers) should be attached to the letter and not separate them.

I run the following code:

```
import re

text = "My weight is about 68 kg, +/- 10 grams! I live in U.S.A. at Mr. 
Peter's house!  3,500 calorie rule, which equates a weight alteration 
of 2.2 lb"

pattern = r"""(?:[A-Z]\.)+ |\d+(?:\.\d+)?%?|\w/.+$\s-|\w+(?:[-']\w+)*|
(?:[+/\-@&*]|/.$/)"""

print (re.findall(pattern, text))
```

The Output:

```
['My', 'weight', 'is', 'about', '68', 'kg', '+', '/', '-', '10', 
 'grams', 'I', 'live', 'in', 'U.S.A. ', 'at', 'Mr', "Peter's", 'house',
 '3', '500', 'calorie', 'rule', 'which', 'equates', 'a', 'weight',
 'alteration', 'of', '2.2', 'lb'
]
```

There are some mistakes with this code, and I really need help to fix them:

1. It removes all of the punctuation! I want to keep them but separated from the words.
2. The pattern ignores the number contains (,) and remove it. I have added `\d+(?:\,\d+)?%?` to the pattern but it doesn't work appropriately.
3. The pattern also ignore some abbreviation such as `Mr.`

Your help will be very appreciated!

Comment: I don't think that this is utterly possible. How should a regex know if the last point of "U.S.A." is the end of the sentence or not?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you avoid trying to do this with a regex and use a tool that has been designed for the job. The following should deal with `U.S.A.` and also `Peter's`:

```
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer, word_tokenize

text = "My weight is about 68 kg, +/- 10 grams! I live in U.S.A. at Mr. Peter's house!  3,500 calorie rule, which equates a weight alteration of 2.2 lb"

print WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(text)
print word_tokenize(text)
```

This would give you the following possibilities:

```
['My', 'weight', 'is', 'about', '68', 'kg,', '+/-', '10', 'grams!', 'I', 'live', 'in', 'U.S.A.', 'at', 'Mr.', "Peter's", 'house!', '3,500', 'calorie', 'rule,', 'which', 'equates', 'a', 'weight', 'alteration', 'of', '2.2', 'lb']
['My', 'weight', 'is', 'about', '68', 'kg', ',', '+/-', '10', 'grams', '!', 'I', 'live', 'in', 'U.S.A.', 'at', 'Mr.', 'Peter', "'s", 'house', '!', '3,500', 'calorie', 'rule', ',', 'which', 'equates', 'a', 'weight', 'alteration', 'of', '2.2', 'lb']
```

Comment: Ok i will use this tool for sure, but there is a mistake in the output. The punctuation in  'grams!' and 'house!' should be spilt from the word. So, the correct out put should be 'grams', '!', 'house', '!' In this case, can I use regex with this code ?

Comment: You can also investigate `word_tokenize()` as an alternative. I have updated the script.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. The problem in the 2nd output is that apostrophe in name Peter's is separated, and it shouldn't. 'Peter', "'s"

Comment: I add this to the code in order to fix apostrophe but it doesn't work.

pattern= (r"(?:[^\W\d_](?:[^\W\d_]|['\-_])+[^\W\d_])")
nltk.regexp_tokenize(text, pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to work with full blown natural language processing tools, I suggest you work with a simpler pattern and plan on some post parsing cleanup.  Trying to solve *everything* within the pattern match is tricky and may continue to fail as new syntax elements are introduced.  That said, here's a simpler pattern approach that I believe handles most of the exceptions that concerned you:

```
import re

text = "My weight is about 68 kg, +/- 10 grams! I live in U.S.A. at Mr. Peter's house!  3,500 calorie rule, which equates a weight alteration of 2.2 lb"

pattern = r"(\s+|(?:[A-Z']\.?)+)"

tokens = [token for token in re.split(pattern, text, flags=re.I) if token and not token.isspace()]

print(tokens)
```

OUTPUT

```
['My', 'weight', 'is', 'about', '68', 'kg', ',', '+/-', '10', 'grams',
'!', 'I', 'live', 'in', 'U.S.A.', 'at', 'Mr.', "Peter's", 'house', '!',
'3,500', 'calorie', 'rule', ',', 'which', 'equates', 'a', 'weight',
'alteration', 'of', '2.2', 'lb']
```

Rather than `re.findall()`, I'm using `re.split()` with pattern retention to isolate tokens in the string (i.e. we split on words.)  As new exceptions arise, evaluate whether it's worth complicating the pattern or whether they can be dealt with pre or post parse.

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. it works fine as the output I want. I am wondering what if i want to use nltk.tokenize. should I use regex also? or the code will be much simpler

Comment: I used nltk & python 3 with your pattern regexp_tokenize(text, pattern=("\s+|(?:[A-Z']\.?)+")), but it shows me this:  ['M',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 'I',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 'U.S.A.',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 'M',
 ' ',
 'P',
 "'",
 ' ',
 '  ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ',
 ' ']

Comment: @BeautifulMind, as I noted in my explanation, my pattern was designed for `re.split()`, which applies patterns differently than other regex functions, followed by a comprehension to remove empty strings and whitespace.  The `regexp_tokenize()` function applies patterns in a different manner which is [summarized in the code comments at the top of the regexp_tokenize() source file.](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it.